# Compile .IL at runtime C#

Tags: c#, cil

I have no idea how to do compile IL code at runtime.
I use .NET core 3.1 and I can generate a string which contains

```
.assembly extern mscorlib {}
.assembly Hello {}
.module Hello.exe

.class Hello.Program
extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method static void Main(string[] args)
    cil managed
    {
        .entrypoint

        ldstr "H"
        call void[mscorlib]
            System.Console::
        Write(string)

        ldstr "i"
        call void[mscorlib]
            System.Console::
        Write(string)

        ret
    }
}
```

But how do I then compile the file? I want to do it at runtime.
(ignore the bad IL code)

Comment: `At runtime` .... from what runtime? Compile during .NET Core runtime?

Comment: Could you specify a little more detailed what exactly it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean like "how to shell ilasm at runtime" ? or are you looking for something like like `TypeBuilder` / `ILGenerator` ? (where you can combine opcodes, but using an object model rather than IL as text)

Comment: You looking for something like [`Reflection.Emit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: Or maybe [`Linq.Expressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

So, i found out how to do it. I copied the ilasm.exe and fusion.dll from my .net framework folder and then i saved the string to a file and then i used ProcessInfo to run `ilasm file`. That then outputted the exe i wanted.

For anybody who is wondering, ilasm.exe is located in
*C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\Verison*
if you replace verison with the framework verison, for example v4.0.30319.

Thanks to anybody who tried to help!